# Why does checking out a git tag bring the wrong version of the code?

Tags: git

Step1: We have master, modify some files, commit, pull, tag, push --tags. Everything works.

Then we go to another computer and we do: git fetch, git tag -l shows the tagnames, git checkout -b tagname ... however the modified files from step 1 are not there...  why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the `-b` option.

```
git checkout -b <new_branch> [<start_point>]
```

This means that you're creating a new branch called `tagname`. Since you didn't specify a start point, Git assumes you want it pointed at the current `HEAD`.

To simply check out a tag, just drop the `-b`:

```
git checkout tagname
```

If you want to create a new branch from the tag, give it a name and the correct starting point.

```
git checkout -b new_branch_name tagname
```

Comment: Or if you want a new branch based on the tag do git checkout branchname tagname

Comment: When I did it without -b , git replied that I should add the -b so it would have a branch... but thank you.

Comment: @smorhaim git is warning you that code could be lost - but like all warning if you dont care and know what you are doing it is useless. Behove the warnings ;-)